# Jboss stop working when user connection over 5000

Tags: java, performance, jboss, connection

i use jboss application server 4 , when user less than 5000 jboss work correctly and every things is ok

but the problem occurred when users over than 5000 connected to jboss , after 5 to 15 minute jboss locked and do not work correctly

i check jconsole , and every resource ( Heap , thread , memory , cpu and etc.) is ok.

i dont know what is the problem , is there any solution ?

Comment: you can't ask for solutions until you figure out what is wrong. That is still your job to do, you can't skip out on it no matter how hard it is to do. I can give you only one hint: there is no reason to believe the problem is within JBoss, it might as well be in your network or the settings of the machine you run it all on. Widen your scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not jboss problem , if you want the better performance Use Load Balancer to divide threads between servers.